# Apache fileserver: authentication respecting underlying permissions and ACL's insted of user which Apache is running

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, file-server

This is my situation: I have the same large volume mounted in many hosts at the same time using Lustre and exporting it trough many protocols (FTP, CIFS, NFS and HTTP).

On Apache I have configured this directory using LDAP authentication. The problem is: when the user logs into a directory via http, Apache will index the files to the user and follows the permission according to the user that Apache is running (in my case, apache).

What I want is a way to serve the files via http and after user authentication, he can browse files and directories with the user he just logged in, following directory permissions and ACL's.

Is there a way to do this via Apache? If not, any other HTTP solution to this?

Comment: Setting the group would be easier using the sticky bit on the directory. For ``httpd`` to change the file owner of an uploaded file, it would need to run as the root user all the time instead of dropping its privileges to a normal user. I will think about it but I do not believe this is possible.